# Spring Endpoint mapping

Tags: java, spring, mapping, endpoint

I have a problem in my `spring-ws-servlet.xml` file to define a endpoint im doing it this way:

```
<bean id="MM7Endpoint" class="pl.famoc.test.ws.FamocCaEndpoint" />
```

but i got the Error with code:

```
Class 'pl.famoc.test.ws.FamocCaEndpoint' not found
```

And i am sure that FamocCaEndpoint.java which contain deffinition of my `@Endpoint` is in the package `pl.famoc.test.ws` Any hints?

Comment: is the jar containing said class on the classpath?

Comment: Which jar? FamocCaEndpoint is class created by me.

Comment: then the jar you are creating with your class in it.

Comment: I am afraid i do not understand you :(

Comment: Your class has to be on the classpath in some manner in order for it to be picked up by spring. I was assuming you were packing the class into a jar, but that doesn't have to be the case. Is your class on the classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to instantiate your "by hand" in your main method or servlet. If you get a `ClassNotFoundException` something might be wrong with your runtime classpath. Note that under certain circumstances, this exception is also thrown when a depend class was not found when the static constructor was invoked (=the first time the class failed to instantiate). All subsequent attempts to instantiate the class will just give you the CNF-Exception. So it might be worth looking out for exceptions that might be thrown prior to this.